# Push Down Automaton to detect RNA hairpins

Tags: c++, bioinformatics, state-machine

For one of my assignments I am supposed to write a Push Down Automaton. It's supposed to receive a string that has to be checked if it's an RNA Hairpin.

For example: gacgcaaguc would be one, since the gac is the opposite of the guc, and the four in the middle have to be either gcaa or gaaa.

I already have a working program which, however, checks each possible case. It has 15 `if` statements, one for each case, and I am sure there is a better way.

Now I am looking for a more elegant way in C++ to check these cases:

```
S -> aW1u | uW1a | gW1c | cW1g
W1-> aW2u | uW2a | gW2c | cW2g
W2-> aW3u | uW3a | gW3c | cW3g
W3-> gW4a
W4->  ca  |  aa
```

As you probably know the right side gets filled into a Stack, and once I reach half the String, I check if the Stack and the other half of my String align. I didn't understand PDAs too well, so maybe you have some help for a guy who is new to this.

HPP:

```
#include <stack>

class PDA
{
public:

    enum Language {
      HAIRPIN, // accepts RNA Hairpins
      BRACKETS // Zusatzaufgabe
    };

    enum State {
      IN_PROGRESS = 0, // sequence is valid so far, but not complete
      SUCCESS = 1,     // currently in accepting state, i.e. stack is empty after reading # symbol
      FAIL = 2         // sequence is not in language
    };

    /// Constructor, which specifies which language to check (HAIRPIN by default)
    /// and internally builds up the production rules
    PDA(const Language l = Language::HAIRPIN);

    /// Read the next symbol and internally traverse states
    /// If a fail state was reached in the previous call, the fail state will be maintained
    /// @param a Symbol to read 
    /// @return current state of PDA
    State next(const char a);

    /// Reset the automaton to a state as if newly constructed
    /// I.e. init stack and set state to s0.
    void reset();

protected:
    /// YOUR Member variables and functions

  State transitionfunction(char b, State cur, char stacktop);
  State current;
  std::stack<char> stark;
  int statechange;
};
```

CPP:

```
#include <stack>
#include "PDA.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    PDA::PDA(const Language l) {
      current = IN_PROGRESS;
      stark.push('$');
      statechange = 0;
    }

    PDA::State PDA::next(const char a) {
      if (statechange == 1) {
        if (stark.top() == '$') {
          return PDA::SUCCESS;
        }
        else if (stark.top() == a) {
          stark.pop();
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else {
          return PDA::FAIL;
        }
      }
      else {
        return transitionfunction(a, current, stark.top());
      }
    }

    void PDA::reset() {
      current = IN_PROGRESS;
      while (!stark.empty()) {
        stark.pop();
      }
      stark.push('$');
      statechange = 0;
    }

    PDA::State PDA::transitionfunction(const char b, PDA::State cur, const char stacktop) {
      if (cur == PDA::FAIL) {
        return PDA::FAIL;
      }

      else if (stacktop =='$') {

        if (b == 'a') {
          stark.push('u');
          stark.push('1');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'c') {
          stark.push('g');
          stark.push('1');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'g') {
          stark.push('c');
          stark.push('1');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'u') {
          stark.push('a');
          stark.push('1');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else {
          return PDA::FAIL;
        }
      }

      else if (stacktop =='1') {

        if (b == 'a') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('u');
          stark.push('2');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'c') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('g');
          stark.push('2');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'g') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('c');
          stark.push('2');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'u') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('a');
          stark.push('2');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else {
          return PDA::FAIL;
        }
      }

      else if (stacktop =='2') {

        if (b == 'a') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('u');
          stark.push('3');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if (b == 'c') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('g');
          stark.push('3');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
      }
        else if (b == 'g') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('c');
          stark.push('3');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
      }
        else if (b == 'u') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('a');
          stark.push('3');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }

        else {
          return PDA::FAIL;
        }
      }

      else if (stacktop == '3') {
        if(b == 'g'){
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('a');
          stark.push('4');
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }

        else {
          return PDA::FAIL;
        }
      }

      else if (stacktop == '4') {
        if(b == 'c'){
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('a');
          statechange = 1;
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }
        else if(b == 'a') {
          stark.pop();
          stark.push('a');
          statechange = 1;
          return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
        }

        else {
          return PDA::FAIL;
        }
      }
    }
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PDA.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Please only enter one string" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string a = argv[1];

    if (a.length() != 10) {
        cout << "The string should have length 10" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    PDA::State final = PDA::IN_PROGRESS;

    PDA testpin;

    for (uint i = 0; i <= a.length(); i++) {
        final = testpin.next(a[i]);
        if (final == PDA::FAIL) {
            cout << "FAIL" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (final == PDA::SUCCESS) {
            cout << "ACCEPT" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with a PDA! It seems like a good way to approach this problem. I see 2 big issues with this: 1)the naming of your variables, and 2) the high number of magic values. Here are my thoughts.

## Naming

In `main()` for example, the user enters a `string`. I assume the `string` is intended to represent a sequence of bases? If so, it should be called something like `base_sequence`.

Similarly, the argument names in your functions tend to be a single character which conveys no meaning whatsoever to a reader. In the constructor to `PDA`, you have an argument named `l`. A single lowercase letter L is a really bad variable name because it looks a lot like a number 1 at first glance. Someone reading the code could easily confuse one for the other, so at least call it `lng` or `lang`, or better yet, `language`. (Or, since it's not actually used ever anywhere, get rid of it!)

The `next` method of `PDA` takes a single `char` named `a`. Looking at the interface for this class, I have no idea what `a` represents. The comment says `symbol to be read.` Why not name it that way? Something like `nextSymbol`, or `nextInput`, or better yet, `next_base` since it represents a base from the base sequence. Also, the name `next` conveys very little. Next what? How about `nextState()` or `processNextBase()`? And the `transitionfunction()` function has both of those problems as well. Again, `b` is a base, so name it that way. You don't usually need to put the word `function` in the name of a function (unless it's returning a function pointer, for example).

And why is your `stack` called `stark`?

## Magic Values

In `transitionfunction()`, what does it mean that the top of the stack contains the character `$`? Or `1` or `2`, or any other value? You should either make named constants for them or define an enumerated type for them. That way, someone reading your code will understand the purpose of them.

## Simplify

I think your `transitionfunction()` function could be simplified in a number of ways. I'll break them down in order of easiest to hardest.

First, you don't need any of the top-level `else`s since once you enter one of them, the function returns. So the structure could be more like this:

```
if (cur == PDA::FAIL) {
    return cur;
}

if (stacktop == '$') {
    //... internal "if"s
}

if (stacktop == '1') {
    // ... internal "if"s
}
etc.
```

Next, it might make sense to break the body of the top-most `if`s into separate functions. So something like this:

```
if (stacktop == '$') {
   return handleS(b);
}

if (stacktop == '1') {
    return handle1(b);
}

if (stacktop == '2') {
    return handle2(b);
}
... etc.
```

Of course, I'd name the handlers something clearer than `handleX` to make it clear what those states represent.

You can then rearrange the above into a `switch` statement like this:

```
switch (stacktop) {
    case '$':
        return handleS(b);
    break;

    case '1':
        return handle1(b);
    break;

    case '2':
        return handle2(b);
    break;
    ...etc.
};
```

You can do the same in the `handleX()` functions:

```
switch (b) {
    case 'a':
        stark.push('u');
        stark.push('1');
        return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
    break;

    case 'c':
        //... code for the 'c' base
    break;

    ... etc.
}
```

But do you notice something? Every case in the `handleX()` functions will consist of up to 4 operations:

1. optionally pop the stack
2. push a base
3. optionally push a number
4. optionally set the state change to 1

And then they return `PDA::IN_PROGRESS`. This seems like a potential candidate for a table-driven design. You could define a `struct` that holds these things. Something like this:

```
struct StateChange {
    bool popStack;
    char base;
    char number; // use a better name here
    bool setStateChange;
    StateChange(bool popIt, char newBase, char newNumber, bool shouldChangeState) : popStack(popIt), base(newBase), number (newNumber), setStateChange(shouldChangeState);
};
```

Then you can create `std::map` of these. Let's look at the `$` case:

```
using StateChangeMap = std::map<char, StateChange>;
StateChangeMap dollarStates;
dollarStates [ 'a' ] = StateChange(false, 'u', '1', false);
dollarStates [ 'c' ] = StateChange(false, 'g', '1', false);
// ... etc. for the rest of the '$' states
```

Then you can put each of those into another `map` where the key is the `stacktop` value that's passed into `transitionfunction()`. Your transition function now looks something like:

```
PDA::State PDA::transitionfunction(const char b, PDA::State cur, const char stacktop) {
    if (cur == PDA::FAIL) {
        return PDA::FAIL;
    }

    StateChange nextState = transitionMap [ stacktop ][ b ];
    if (nextState.popStack) {
        stark.pop();
    }
    stark.push(nextState.base);
    if (nextState.number != '0') { // Here I'm using '0' to represent not pushing a number
        stark.push(nextState.number);
    }
    if (nextState.setStateChange)
    {
        statechange = 1;
    }
    return PDA::IN_PROGRESS;
}
```

Note that you'll either need to use `std::map::find()` rather than the `operator[]` that I used if you haven't sanitized the input, or you'll need to sanitize the input so you never get an invalid state value.